# Attenuation of ultrasonic waves and frequency

Tags: acoustics

Attenuation of ultrasonic waves is a function of the frequency of the waves, higher is the frequency more is the attenuation in a given length of a medium. Is there any formula which captures the relationship between frwquency and attenuation?

Comment: This depends on the medium where the ultrasonic waves are propagating

Comment: I understand that there will be other factors affecting the attenuation. So, is there any formula which incorporates medium characteristics as well, or any formula developed for any given medium?

Comment: This is what I have found:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_attenuation
http://courses.washington.edu/bioen508/Lecture6-US.pdf